# My SSD free space dissapeared. What should I do?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

I have a problem with SSD free space. 
It says, that free space on drive C is around 5GB but [when i select everything in hard drive folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJgDS.jpg) it says, that I used only 44GB. If i'm not bat at maths there is still around 75GB of free space but my PC says, that I have only 5GB.
[I'm uploading photo of free space on my drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8h9Y.jpg) and I'm looking forward for your answers.

Explanatory Notes :

"Všetko v priečinku C:" - everything in C: folder

"Využité miesto" - used space

"Voľné miesto" - free space

Comment: Did you try `Čistenie disku` button (in English: `Disk Clean-up`)?

Comment: i have already tried this one.. :// It says that i can delete only 10GB, still not 70